# How to print function name without hard code string?

Tags: c#, function, printing, line

c language has macro like **FILE**/**LINE** to print file name and code line number

So how does C# language achieve same goal, is it possible to do, or require assembly packages?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question title and question body seem to be at odds with each other. Can you make them ask the same thing?

Comment: Do you mean [Caller Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)?

Comment: @Sweeper See I thought OP meant `nameof()` going by the question title.

Comment: I am confident this is a x-y-Question. What do want to do? (In other words: what do you need file/line for?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8), i would be wary about doing this though, it will come at a performance cost and is likely to give you issues in release .

> Represents a stack trace, which is an ordered collection of one or
>   more stack frames.

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(0, true);
var sf = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
Console.WriteLine("FileName: {0}", sf.GetFileName());
Console.WriteLine("Line Number:{0} ",sf.GetFileLineNumber());
Console.WriteLine("Function Name:{0}",sf.GetMethod ());
```